# Azure Active Directory B2C in a C# webapplication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are trying to figure out AAD B2C and more specific the feature of ‘single sign on’ in web applications. Whilst the installation and configuration in Azure has been without any significant issues, we struggle with the understanding of the custom implementation in web applications that we build.

Every code example that we can find in Microsoft Documentation, speaks of a C# web application in combination with an API and, as far as we can see, explicitly need this API to function. Examples in other languages, like Python/Django, that we find for the implementation of the B2C feature do not seem to have the ‘requirement’ of an API.

We find it hard to understand why we should build an API next to the Web Application itself. We think this may not even be the case, but cant seem to find a working example without the API.

1. Is there a hidden purpose of having an API in the C# project?
2. Are there any (C#) code examples that do not require this (in our eyes) “overcomplicated” design to function?

We are not afraid of API’s, but we like to implement the most simplest design and only complicate things when needed. Having the simplest examples online makes it easiest to understand the framework, protocols and workflows.

The basic example that we found (amongst others):
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

Comment: This sample is just a web app signing in a user w/B2C. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C...and this [branch](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/jmprieur/removingUis) specifically has updates for B2C with asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need an API, but generally is the cleaner way to go rather than building a monolith app. You can simply delete the API project from the Web app Web API samples. And remove the msal code that obtains a token to that API.